# Not the same hash value in c# and php

Tags: c#, php, unicode, md5

I have a web service developed in c#. 
It uses **MD5** to generate session key.

### c# :

```
public static string GetMD5(string pTxt)
{
    string sCTxt = "";
    byte[] aTxt;
    UnicodeEncoding oEnc = new UnicodeEncoding();
    aTxt = oEnc.GetBytes(pTxt);
    HashAlgorithm oHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] aCTxt = oHash.ComputeHash(aTxt);
    foreach (byte b in aCTxt)
        sCTxt += String.Format("{0:X2}", b);
    return (sCTxt);
}
```

For several reasons, I have to make the same GetMD5 method in **PHP**.
Of course, the basic md5() function does not return the same hash (because of the UNICODE)

I tried to simulate the code in PHP but with no success

### php:

```
public function HexToBytes($s) {
    return join('', array_map('chr', array_map('hexdec', str_split($s, 2))));
}

public function GetMD5($pStr) {
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($pStr, 'UTF-16LE', 'ASCII');
    $h = $this->HexToBytes(hash_hmac('md5', $data, ''));
    return (base64_encode($h));
}
```

Any idea why the result are not the same ?

Thanks in advance

---

**

### FIXED! Thanks!

**

For those interested, here is the PHP method that matches the c# one

```
public function str2hex($string) {
   $hex = "";
   for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
      $hex .= (strlen(dechex(ord($string[$i]))) < 2) ? "0" . dechex(ord($string[$i])) : dechex(ord($string[$i]));       
   return $hex;
}

public function GetMD5($pStr) {
   $data = mb_convert_encoding($pStr, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
   $h = $this->str2hex(md5($data, true));
   return strtoupper($h);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your C# version is hex encoding the result where the php version is base64 encoding the result. That will certainly give different results.

Comment: Plus the PHP code is doing an HMAC instead of s straight hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just overcomplicated your methods. The following alternatives worked for me:

### [C#](http://ideone.com/oUdN7):

```
public static string GetMD5(string text)
{
    byte[] textBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(textBytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

### [PHP](http://ideone.com/QfFbq):

```
public function GetMD5($pStr) {
    return base64_encode(
              md5(mb_convert_encoding($pStr, "UTF8", "Unicode"), true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would be okay if the c# hash was made with UTF-8 encoding. But it is made in Unicode encoding and I cannot change it...

Comment: Where exactly it is in Unicode: C# or PHP side? You can convert it to be UTF8. (Please see updated PHP code.)

Comment: I just made some tests. Changing the enconding type to UTF-8 in the c# method works.

But i'd like to keep the UnicodeEncoding oEnc = new UnicodeEncoding();

Comment: Ok I got it! You've quite helpful !
Here is the final PHP code needed:

public function GetMD5($pStr) {
 $data = mb_convert_encoding($pStr, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
 $h = $this->str2hex(md5($data, true));
 return strtoupper($h);
}

Thanks!

Comment: @Elian, probably you don't need to use `str2hex` when you use [`md5`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) with the second argument set to `true` as it should return binary data on itself.